# bmp to GIF animations

Tags: matlab

How to convert images to GIF animation in matlab.
Let's say that it's from C:\folder1 and images are inside that folder.
Do I need to frame them or anything? And can it be done with a loop? (for now I need a simple GIF animaton).

THNX in advance.

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can see how to in the link I have posted, but lets modify it so you can know how to do it with any image:

```
% Load, prepare, do whatever you need to create plots, imshow or something graphic

figure(1)
filename = 'test.gif';
fps=15 % change as you wish
for n = 1:framenumber
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      % Plot here whatever you want ex: imshow(img{n});
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      drawnow
      frame = getframe(1);
      im = frame2im(frame);
      [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256);
      if n == 1;
          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf,'Delaytime',1/fps);
      else
          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append','Delaytime',1/fps);
      end
end
```

Comment: Should it save at the end as a gif? Because after adding the loop,it saves only the last image in GIF format.

Comment: It will save whatever you plot in the part where I wrote "plot here..." in each frame. So if you only plot 1 image it will save only last one. if you plot different images in each iteration it will be an animated gif. This code works for sure in Matlab 2013b because I am ising it to create gifs. @GramozÇubreli